# Methods are Undefined

Tags: ruby, google-search-console, google-api-ruby-client

I have a legacy Rails app, and I'm trying to get Google Search Console data to show to customers. I have successfully gotten authorization to work, however, when I try to access **any** of the [methods](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google/Apis/WebmastersV3/WebmastersService) listed in:

```
Class: Google::Apis::WebmastersV3::WebmastersService
```

I get an 'undefined method' error.

Ruby: 1.9.3

Rails: 2.3.17

google-api-client (0.3.0)

Here's my code:

```rb
    @client = Google::APIClient.new
    @client.authorization.access_token = @oauth_response['access_token']
    @service = @client.discovered_api('webmasters', 'v3')
    @client_response = @client.execute(:api_method => @service.list_sitemaps, :parameters => {'site_url' => 'https://sitename.com'})
```

I'm expecting a json payload that I can parse, but I am getting the following error:

```
undefined method `list_sitemaps' for #<Google::APIClient::API:0x3fda2b78fc04 ID:webmasters:v3>
```

What am I missing? I've been searching for days. I understand that this might not even be possible, given that the google-api-client gem is so old. I am using, I think, the correct pre 0.9 syntax as described [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client/blob/master/MIGRATING.md).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

I've tried a different route, and I have been able to retrieve an access token, with which I use to create a [Legato](https://github.com/tpitale/legato) user.

```
   @oauth_options = {
      body: {
        client_id: 'xxxxxxxx',
        client_secret: 'xxxxxx',
        refresh_token: 'xxxxxxxxx',
        grant_type: 'refresh_token'
      },
      headers: {
        'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
    }
    @oauth_response = HTTParty.post('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', @oauth_options)
    @user = Legato::User.new(@oauth_response['access_token'])
    @accounts = @user.accounts
```

From there, I get the following unhelpful error:

`undefined method 'get' for #<String:0x007fd2299e6fd0>`

```
/Users/shorepound/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@bizyellow/gems/legato-0.7.0/lib/legato/request.rb:25:in 'oauth_2_response'
/Users/shorepound/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@bizyellow/gems/legato-0.7.0/lib/legato/request.rb:15:in 'raw_response'
/Users/shorepound/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@bizyellow/gems/legato-0.7.0/lib/legato/request.rb:11:in 'response'
/Users/shorepound/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@bizyellow/gems/legato-0.7.0/lib/legato/user.rb:14:in 'request'
/Users/shorepound/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@bizyellow/gems/legato-0.7.0/lib/legato/management/finder.rb:11:in 'all'
/Users/shorepound/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@bizyellow/gems/legato-0.7.0/lib/legato/user.rb:21:in 'accounts'
/Users/shorepound/Development/apu_new/app/controllers/traffic_controller.rb:37:in 'index'
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT 2:**

It seems that I was using a string access_token and not an oauth access_token object. Adding the following got everything working for me:

```
    oauth_client = OAuth2::Client.new('', '', {
      authorize_url: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
      token_url: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token'
    })

    access_token = OAuth2::AccessToken.new(oauth_client, oauth_response['access_token'], expires_in: 1.hour)
```

Here's how it all looks together:

```
    oauth_options = {
      body: {
        client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
        client_secret: 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET',
        refresh_token: 'YOUR_REFRESH_TOKEN',
        grant_type: 'refresh_token'
      },
      headers: {
        'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
    }
    oauth_response = HTTParty.post('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', oauth_options)

    oauth_client = OAuth2::Client.new('', '', {
      authorize_url: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
      token_url: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token'
    })

    access_token = OAuth2::AccessToken.new(oauth_client, oauth_response['access_token'], expires_in: 1.hour)

    @user = Legato::User.new(access_token)
```

**EDIT 3:**

The saga continues! I dug into the code of the `google-api-client` gem (version 0.3.0) and figured out that duh, this gem is too old to access the new methods in more current gem versions. Updating Ruby and Rails is not an option, so I'm still trying to get this to work with the old 0.3.0 gem. I'm so close!

Here's my code:

```
@gsc_response = @gsc_client.execute(
 :version => 'v3',
 :api_method => 'webmasters.searchanalytics.query',
 :headers => {
  'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
 },
 :body => {
  startDate:  @startDate,
  endDate:  @endDate,
 },
 :parameters => {
  siteUrl:    'https://sitename.com'
 }
)
```

Here's the post request:

```
Google Service Request: ["POST", "https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/https:%2F%2Fsitename.com/searchAnalytics/query", [["Content-Type", "application/json"], ["Authorization", "OAuth **removed**"], ["Cache-Control", "no-store"]], ["[:startDate, \"2019-07-05\"][:endDate, \"2019-10-03\"]"]]
```

And here's the response:

```
Google Service Response: #, @parameters={:siteUrl=>"https://bizyellow.com"}, @headers={"Content-Type"=>"application/json"}, @body={:startDate=>"2019-07-05", :endDate=>"2019-10-03"}>, @request=["POST", "https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/https:%2F%2Fsitename.com/searchAnalytics/query", [["User-Agent", "google-api-ruby-client/0.3.0 Mac OS X/10.12.6"], ["Content-Type", "application/json"], ["Authorization", "OAuth ***removed***"], ["Cache-Control", "no-store"]], ["[:startDate, \"2019-07-05\"][:endDate, \"2019-10-03\"]"]], @response=[400, [["Vary", "X-Origin, Origin,Accept-Encoding"], ["Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8"], ["Date", "Thu, 03 Oct 2019 19:59:05 GMT"], ["Expires", "Thu, 03 Oct 2019 19:59:05 GMT"], ["Cache-Control", "private, max-age=0"], ["X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff"], ["X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN"], ["X-Xss-Protection", "1; mode=block"], ["Server", "GSE"], ["Alt-Svc", "quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\",h3-Q048=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000"], ["Accept-Ranges", "none"], ["Transfer-Encoding", "chunked"]], ["{\n \"error\": {\n \"errors\": [\n {\n \"domain\": \"global\",\n \"reason\": \"parseError\",\n \"message\": \"Parse Error\"\n }\n ],\n \"code\": 400,\n \"message\": \"Parse Error\"\n }\n}\n"]]>
```

I'm really at a loss, as `Parse Error` doesn't really give me much to go on. Any help at all would really save me from this awful hell.

**EDIT 4:**

I finally got it working, and it's not pretty. I concatenated the dates and manipulated it all into a string that the API could parse:

```
@start_date = ['startDate', '2019-07-01'].to_s.gsub(',',':').gsub('[','{').gsub(']','}')
@end_date = ['endDate', '2019-10-01'].to_s.gsub(',',':').gsub('[','{').gsub(']','}')
@dates = @start_date.sub('}',',') + @end_date.sub('{','')
```

And then passed the string as the 'merged body':

`:merged_body => @dates,`

Hopefully, this will help someone.

**FINAL EDIT**

Here's a prettier string that is passed to the merged_body, which included a filter to get data for a particular path:

```
startDate = 90.days.ago.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
endDate = DateTime.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
body_str = "{\"startDate\": \"#{startDate}\",\"endDate\": \"#{endDate}\",\"dimensionFilterGroups\":[{\"filters\":[{\"dimension\": \"page\",\"expression\": \"#{business_path(@business)}\",\"operator\": \"contains\"}]}]}"
```